# Automate git flow initialization

Tags: git, git-flow

How can I automate git flow initialization by specifing my own branch names, version prefixes etc. I tried using shell script but wasnt able to send data to the script after I execute:

`git flow init`

I don't want default values I want to specify my own but without having to write them each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the .git/config file to reflect the required configuration.

Compare you .git/config file before and after running "git flow init".
It will add the selected configuration. For example, the default configuration lines are:

```
[gitflow "branch"]
        master = master
        develop = develop
[gitflow "prefix"]
        feature = feature/
        release = release/
        hotfix = hotfix/
        support = support/
        versiontag =
```

Comment: https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/wiki/Reference:-git-flow-config you mean this ?